Undefined reference to cblas_* with cmake on windows
I'working on a project that uses SAF (Spatial Audio Framework) which has OpenBlas and LAPACK as Dependecies. (The Project includes a lot of libraries so I only show the code that relates to my problem: BLAS)
I'm trying to figure out how I can link the project with OpenBlas, but nothing worked.
I use cmake's FETCHCONTENT to get LAPACK which also contains BLAS.
I tried:
target_link_libraries(dev_example PUBLIC openblas) # or libopenblas or cblas or libblas

which resulted in cannot find -lopenblas.
Now I tried to specify the library directly
SET(OPENBLAS_LIBRARY ${lapack_BINARY_DIR}/lib/libblas.a) and get a lot of undefined references like undefined reference to 'cblas_sgemm'
I also tried linking against libopenblas.a from the precompiled binaries from the OpenBlas Repo - same as above.

My CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(dev_example VERSION 1.0 LANGUAGES C CXX)

include(FetchContent)

FETCHCONTENT_DECLARE(
        lapack
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/Reference-lapack/lapack
        GIT_TAG        master
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(lapack)
FetchContent_GetProperties(lapack)
if(NOT lapack_POPULATED)
    FetchContent_Populate(lapack)
endif()

set(OPENBLAS_HEADER_PATH ${lapack_SOURCE_DIR}/CBLAS/include)
set(LAPACKE_HEADER_PATH ${lapack_SOURCE_DIR}/LAPACKE/include ${lapack_BINARY_DIR}/include)

SET(LAPACKE_LIBRARY ${lapack_BINARY_DIR}/lib/liblapack.a)
SET(OPENBLAS_LIBRARY ${lapack_BINARY_DIR}/lib/libblas.a)

add_executable(dev_example WIN32
        main.cpp
        )

target_include_directories(dev_example PUBLIC
        ${lapack_SOURCE_DIR}/CBLAS/include
        ${lapack_BINARY_DIR}/include
)


target_link_libraries(dev_example PUBLIC
        ${OPENBLAS_LIBRARY}
        )

How can I link Blas correctly?
I made sure that libblas.a is located in the given directory.
I was also wondering if I'm even using the correct BLAS library because all the undefined refences are prefixed with cblas_ like cblas_sgemm while libblas.a only contains Symbols like sgemm without the prefix.
Compiler: gcc.exe (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0

Could you also post your dev_example -> main.cpp?

The code itself doesn't contain a reference to BLAS, but  I only include #include "saf.h"  and #include "ambi_bin.h" which require BLAS. I don't even call a funtion from SAF yet, just including it for now and I already get this linking error.

In your own answer:

I assume that LAPACK on Github contains a different implementation of BLAS and not OpenBLAS.

The libblas.a that is built along with liblapack.a with repo https://github.com/Reference-lapack/lapack
is a Fortran BLAS library. That is why all its symbols lack the CBLAS prefix cblas_. As per the repo's README,
it does contain a CBLAS source tree but it does not tell you that this is not built by default. Or that you have to configure the CMake build with
-DCBLAS=ON, and then, instead of (or after) running make you
must run make cblas. The build will then output a libcblas.a.
As you found, OpenBLAS builds a CBLAS library
libopenblas.a by default with header files equipped for linkage with C++. Regarding
that repo:

FetchContent didn't set any library variable for BLAS, unlike find_package usually would.

It doesn't, but it does set:
openblas_SOURCE_DIR
openblas_BINARY_DIR

So just as far as linking against libopenblas is concerned, you can have a CMakeLists.txt
on the lines:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(dev_example VERSION 1.0 LANGUAGES C CXX)

include(FetchContent)

FetchContent_Declare(
        openblas
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/OpenMathLib/OpenBLAS.git
        GIT_TAG        v0.3.28
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(openblas)
FetchContent_GetProperties(openblas)

set(openblas_HDR_DIRS ${openblas_SOURCE_DIR} ${openblas_BINARY_DIR})
set(openblas_LIB_DIRS ${openblas_BINARY_DIR}/lib)

add_executable(dev_example
        main.cpp
        )

target_include_directories(dev_example PRIVATE
        ${openblas_HDR_DIRS}
        )

target_link_directories(dev_example PRIVATE
        ${openblas_LIB_DIRS}
        )

target_link_libraries(dev_example PRIVATE
        openblas
        )
        

The reason for the inclusion of ${openblas_BINARY_DIR} in target_include_directories is
the fact that an autotools-style header config.h is generated in the build directory.


I also tried linking against libopenblas.a from the precompiled binaries from the OpenBlas Repo - same as above.

I got this wrong. Adding libopenblas.a in target_link_libraries did not work. However using
SET(OPENBLAS_LIBRARY ${dir_to_lib}/libopenblas.a)

to link OpenBLAS did the Job for me. Looks like SAF needs OPENBLAS_LIBRARY set to work correctly. FetchContent didn't set any library variable for BLAS, unlinke find_package usually would.
I assume that LAPACK on Github contains a different implementation of BLAS and not OpenBLAS.
